# How to GroupBy objects by numeric values with tolerance factor?

Tags: c#, linq, math, collections

I have a C# list of objects with the following simplified data:

```
ID, Price
2, 80.0
8, 44.25
14, 43.5
30, 79.98
54, 44.24
74, 80.01
```

I am trying to GroupBy the lowest number while taking into account a tolerance factor. 
for example, in a case of tolerance = 0.02, my expected result should be:

```
44.24 -> 8, 54
43.5 -> 14
79.98 -> 2, 30, 74
```

How can i do this while achieving a good performance for large datasets? 
Is LINQ the way to go in this case?

Comment: I cannot really understand the closing flag nor the downvote - this is indeed a interesting problem - one where I don't see a simple LINQish answer. Indeed I think you need an iterative process for this (you want to classify your data into classes where each one of those has a *diameter* of 0.4 max) - so I think you need a modified cluster analysis algorithm: [centroid based cluster analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Centroid-based_clustering) (modified because you want a fixed similarity and you can iterate till the clusters are small enough)

Comment: `LINQ` is not the best way to solve your problem, but what I first think of linq function is `Aggregate` instead of `Group By`.

Comment: here is how you could start (I think - maybe I try it if I have some time): start with one group where all your data-points are in (you need: min/max/median values) if (max-min) > your tolerance then split the "cluster" into two and repeat this recursively till you have small enough clusters - after this collect your datapoints

Comment: BTW: the 0.4 in my first answer was both a logic and a typing error - of course your diameter will be 0.02 ;)

Comment: To me it is unclear whether the result is expected to be a partition of the input. If this is desired, I believe It cannot be done without sorting the input by `Price` and then, iteratively, fill the classes while the price is still contained within the desired diameter.

Comment: Presumably you're ok with some data points ending up in two groups?  E.g. if your example included `90, 80.03`, would you want your result set to include `80.03 -> 74, 90` ?

Comment: Geoff, no. in that case: 79.98 -> 2, 30, 74, 90. only one group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seemed to me that if you have a large data set you'll want to avoid the straightforward solution of sorting the values and then collecting them as you iterate through the sorted list, since sorting a large collection can be expensive. The most efficient solution I could think of which doesn't do any explicit sorting was to build a tree where each node contains the items where the key falls within a "contiguous" range (where all the keys are within `tolerance` of each other) - the range for each node expands every time an item is added which falls outside the range by less than `tolerance`. I implemented a solution - which turned out to be more complicated and interesting than I expected - and based on my rough benchmarking it looks like doing it this way takes about half as much time as the straightforward solution.

Here's my implementation as an extension method (so you can chain it, although like the normal `Group` method it'll iterate the `source` completely as soon as the result `IEnumerable` is iterated).

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<double, TValue>> GroupWithTolerance<TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<TValue> source,
    double tolerance, 
    Func<TValue, double> keySelector) 
{
    if(source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        
    return GroupWithToleranceHelper<TValue>.Group(source, tolerance, keySelector);
}

private static class GroupWithToleranceHelper<TValue>
{
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<double, TValue>> Group(
        IEnumerable<TValue> source,
        double tolerance, 
        Func<TValue, double> keySelector)
    {
        Node root = null, current = null;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            var key = keySelector(item);
            if(root == null) root = new Node(key);
            current = root;
            while(true){
                if(key < current.Min - tolerance) { current = (current.Left ?? (current.Left = new Node(key))); }
                else if(key > current.Max + tolerance) {current = (current.Right ?? (current.Right = new Node(key)));}
                else 
                {
                    current.Values.Add(item);
                    if(current.Max < key){
                        current.Max = key;
                        current.Redistribute(tolerance);
                    }
                    if(current.Min > key) {
                        current.Min = key;
                        current.Redistribute(tolerance);
                    }       
                    break;
                }   
            }
        }

        if (root != null)
        {
            foreach (var entry in InOrder(root))
            {
                yield return entry;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Return an empty collection
            yield break;
        }
    }
    
    
    private static IEnumerable<IGrouping<double, TValue>> InOrder(Node node)
    {
        if(node.Left != null)
            foreach (var element in InOrder(node.Left))
                yield return element;
        
        yield return node;
        
        if(node.Right != null)
            foreach (var element in InOrder(node.Right))
                yield return element;       
    }   
    
    private class Node : IGrouping<double, TValue>
    {
        public double Min;
        public double Max;
        public readonly List<TValue> Values = new List<TValue>();       
        public Node Left;
        public Node Right;
        
        public Node(double key) {
            Min = key;
            Max = key;
        }   
        
        public double Key { get { return Min; } }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }     
        public IEnumerator<TValue> GetEnumerator() { return Values.GetEnumerator(); }   
        
        public IEnumerable<TValue> GetLeftValues(){
            return Left == null ? Values : Values.Concat(Left.GetLeftValues());
        }
        
        public IEnumerable<TValue> GetRightValues(){
            return Right == null ? Values : Values.Concat(Right.GetRightValues());
        }
        
        public void Redistribute(double tolerance)
        {
            if(this.Left != null) {
                this.Left.Redistribute(tolerance);
                if(this.Left.Max + tolerance > this.Min){
                    this.Values.AddRange(this.Left.GetRightValues());
                    this.Min = this.Left.Min;
                    this.Left = this.Left.Left;
                }
            }
            
            if(this.Right != null) {
                this.Right.Redistribute(tolerance);
                if(this.Right.Min - tolerance < this.Max){
                    this.Values.AddRange(this.Right.GetLeftValues());
                    this.Max = this.Right.Max;
                    this.Right = this.Right.Right;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can switch `double` to another type if you need to (I so wish C# had a `numeric` generic constraint).

Comment: I've implemented this code exactly as written and solved this hard problem, thank you.  Now that it is in use, there is an issue I've found if I try to group a collection with no items.  The null pointer exception happens on the first line of private static 
@SteveRuble IEnumerable<IGrouping<double, TValue>> InOrder(Node node) because the node parameter which is passed in using the root variable, just a few lines above this function, is null.  Can you recommend an edit for foreach (var entry in InOrder(root)) to address the null root variable?

Comment: Steve Ruble, this is a great solution but I've identified cases that cause some items to not be placed in any group.  I've studied this code and haven't been able to nail down the issue.  If I provide you with test data in a test function, would you be willing to find and resolve the issue?

Answer (score 5):

The most straight-forward approach is to design your own `IEqualityComparer<double>`.

```cs
    public class ToleranceEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<double>
    {
        public double Tolerance { get; set; } = 0.02;
        public bool Equals(double x, double y)
        {
            return x - Tolerance <= y && x + Tolerance > y;
        }

        //This is to force the use of Equals methods.
        public int GetHashCode(double obj) => 1;
    }
```

Which you should use like so

```cs
 var dataByPrice = data.GroupBy(d => d.Price, new ToleranceEqualityComparer());
```

Comment: This is going to give you a very sad and slow dictionary where every entry is in the same bucket. I wouldn't use this on large sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new implementation that ultimately passed unit tests that the other two solutions failed.  It implements the same signature as the currently accepted answer.  The unit tests checked to ensure no groups resulted in a min and max value larger than the tolerance and that the number of items grouped matched the items provided.

**How to use**

```
var values = new List<Tuple<double, string>>
{
    new Tuple<double, string>(113.5, "Text Item 1"),
    new Tuple<double, string>(109.62, "Text Item 2"),
    new Tuple<double, string>(159.06, "Text Item 3"),
    new Tuple<double, string>(114, "Text Item 4")
};

var groups = values.GroupWithTolerance(5, a => a.Item1).ToList();
```

**Extension Method**

```
/// <summary>
/// Groups items of an IEnumerable collection while allowing a tolerance that all items within the group will fall within 
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TValue"></typeparam>
/// <param name="source"></param>
/// <param name="tolerance"></param>
/// <param name="keySelector"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<double, TValue>> GroupWithTolerance<TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<TValue> source,
    double tolerance,
    Func<TValue, double> keySelector
)
{
    var sortedValuesWithKey = source
        .Select((a, i) => Tuple.Create(a, keySelector(a), i))
        .OrderBy(a => a.Item2)
        .ToList();
    
    var diffsByIndex = sortedValuesWithKey
        .Skip(1)
        //i will start at 0 but we are targeting the diff between 0 and 1.
        .Select((a, i) => Tuple.Create(i + 1, sortedValuesWithKey[i + 1].Item2 - sortedValuesWithKey[i].Item2))
        .ToList();

    var groupBreaks = diffsByIndex
        .Where(a => a.Item2 > tolerance)
        .Select(a => a.Item1)
        .ToHashSet();

    var groupKeys = new double[sortedValuesWithKey.Count];

    void AddRange(int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        //If there is just one value in the group, take a short cut.
        if (endIndex - startIndex == 0)
        {
            groupKeys[sortedValuesWithKey[startIndex].Item3] = sortedValuesWithKey[startIndex].Item2;
            return;
        }

        var min = sortedValuesWithKey[startIndex].Item2;
        var max = sortedValuesWithKey[endIndex].Item2;

        //If the range is within tolerance, we are done with this group.
        if (max - min < tolerance)
        {
            //Get the average value of the group and assign it to all elements.
            var rangeValues = new List<double>(endIndex - startIndex);
            for (var x = startIndex; x <= endIndex; x++) 
                rangeValues.Add(sortedValuesWithKey[x].Item2);

            var average = rangeValues.Average();

            for (var x = startIndex; x <= endIndex; x++)
                groupKeys[sortedValuesWithKey[x].Item3] = average;

            return;
        }

        //The range is not within tolerance and needs to be divided again.
        //Find the largest gap and divide.
        double maxDiff = -1;
        var splitIndex = -1;
        for (var i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
        {
            var currentDif = diffsByIndex[i].Item2;
            if (currentDif > maxDiff)
            {
                maxDiff = currentDif;
                splitIndex = i;
            }
        }

        AddRange(startIndex, splitIndex);
        AddRange(splitIndex + 1, endIndex);
    }

    var groupStartIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < sortedValuesWithKey.Count; i++)
    {
        //There isn't a group break here, at least not yet, so continue.
        if (!groupBreaks.Contains(i))
            continue;

        AddRange(groupStartIndex, i - 1);
        groupStartIndex = i;
    }

    //Add the last group's keys if we haven't already.
    if (groupStartIndex < sortedValuesWithKey.Count)
        AddRange(groupStartIndex, sortedValuesWithKey.Count - 1);

    return sortedValuesWithKey.GroupBy(a => groupKeys[a.Item3], a => a.Item1);
}
```

Comment: Well, if I feed it `1, 2, 3, 4`, with tolerance `1.1`, I get `[1], [2], [3,4]`. If 3 and 4 belong in one group, why not 1 and two? But the problem lies deeper: in this example 1 and 2 belong in one group, but so do 2 and 3, and hence 1, 2 and 3. Problem: 1 and 3 are more than 1.1 apart. I.e. with such "fuzzy" boundaries the grouping wil always be arbitrary.